# R - Change the order of elements in a list

Tags: r, list

I need to change the order of elements in a `list`. I don't find a patent response in others questions about sort or order a list.

Here is a simple example.

```
Freedom <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2)
Equality <- c(2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1)
TypeCountry <- c("South", "East", "East", "North", "South", "West")

Example <- list(Freedom, Equality, TypeCountry)
names(Example) <- c("Freedom", "Equality", "TypeCountry")
```

The `list` has the order `Freedom`, `Equality` then `TypeCountry` and I want to be able to change the order of the elements (for example `Equality`, `Freedom` then `TypeCountry`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Ex <- Example[c("TypeCountry","Freedom", "Equality")]
```

You specify the order you want.

Answer (score 10):

We can `order` on the `names` of 'Example'

```
ExampleNew <- Example[order(names(Example))]
```